# How to determine degree of freedom for a certain test of interaction?

Tags: interaction, degrees-of-freedom, stratification

The scenario is like this:

I have a cohort with 2000 people, half of them taking DRUG, the other half not taking it. I would like to check interactions between DRUG and the other variables in the model:

- **Method 1:**

  Firstly I got a original model: `y1=a1*AGE+b1*BMI+c1*DRUG`，[`DRUG` is binary: yes-1, no-0]; I got a likelihood 1;

  If I want to test the interaction of `AGE`, `BMI` and `DRUG`, I need another model: `y2=a2*AGE+b2*BMI+c2*DRUG+d*(DRUG*AGE)+e*(DRUG*BMI)`; I got a likelihood 2;

  Then I compare the likelihood of these two models using chi-square test (df=2), and see whether the difference (likelihood 2 minus likelihood) is significant.
- **Method 2:**

  Stratify people into two groups according to DRUG status:

  Group 1: for people taking DRUG (n=1000), model 1: `y1=a1*AGE+b1*BMI`, I got a likelihood 1 (L1);

  Group 2: for people not taking DRUG (n=1000), model 2: `y2=a2*AGE+b2*BMI`, likelihood 2 (L2);

  Then I use all the people (n-2000), model 3:y3=a3*AGE+b3*BMI+d*(DRUG*AGE)+e*(DRUG*BMI), likelihood 3 (L3);

So in order to test the interactions, chi-square=L3/(L1*L2). But the question is: What is the degree of freedom (df)?

Can anyone help? I cannot get the answer.